# Mysql VARCHAR vs VARBINARY

Tags: mysql, binary, char, varchar, varbinary

Will it be more efficient to switch from `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` to `BINARY` and `VARBINARY` respectively? It envolves `strtohex` on `PHP` side and `UNHEX`on `MySQL` side, but discards need of `mysqli_real_escape_string`.
Thanks.

Comment: @Alma Do No, that question is about trailing spaces